# Routing based on requested datatype in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, rest

I'm trying to write REST-behaviour into my ASP.NET MVC2 app, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make the routes work as I want.

I'd like my routing to work like this:

```
/Users/Get/1 <- returns a regular HTML-based reply
/Users/Get.xml/1 <- returns the data from Get as XML
/Users/Get.json/1 <- returns the data as JSon
```

I've tried setting up routes like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Rest", 
 "{controller}/{action}{format}/{id}" (...)
```

But it complains I need a separator between {action} and {format}

also the following:

```
routes.MapRoute("Rest",
     "{controller}/{action}.{format}/{id}" (...)
```

makes the /Users/Get/1 invalid (it needs to be /Users/Get./1 which is unacceptable)

Any suggestions?

-------------EDIT------------------------------------

I have one solution right now, but I'm not really happy with it:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "DefaultWithFormat", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}.{format}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", format = "HTML", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

This works with both /Users/Get.whateverFormat/1 and also /Users/Get/1

Reason for this is that when I just do /Users/Get/1 (without the .format) it skips the first route, and goes to the next which doesn't include a format.
To handle the return I've created an ActionFilterAttribute and override the OnActionExecuted method like this:

```
var type = filterContext.RouteData.Values["format"];
if (type != null && attributes != null)
{
    if (type == "HTML") return;
    if (type.ToString().ToLower() == "xml" && attributes.Any(a => a.AllowedTypes.Any(a2 => a2 == ResponseType.XML)))
    {
        filterContext.Result = new XmlResult(filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        return;
    }
    if (type.ToString().ToLower() == "json" && attributes.Any(a => a.AllowedTypes.Any(a2 => a2 == ResponseType.JSON)))
    {
        filterContext.Result = new JsonResult() { Data = (filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model), JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
        return;
    }
}
```

And I also have a ResponseTypeAttribute which allows me to decorate the actions with what returntype they should allow:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class ResponseTypeAttribute : Attribute
{
    List<ResponseType> allowedTypes;

    public List<ResponseType> AllowedTypes
    {
        get { return allowedTypes; }
        set { allowedTypes = value; }
    }

    public ResponseTypeAttribute(params ResponseType[] allowedTypes)
    {
        this.allowedTypes = new List<ResponseType>();
        this.allowedTypes.AddRange(allowedTypes);
    }


}

public enum ResponseType
{
    XML, JSON
}
```

The XmlResult is just a simple object serializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brad Wilson made a talk with title Advanced ASP.NET MVC2 where he has shown an example how to do exactly what you want. You can download the slides and example code here:

http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/talks.html

(It is the first talk on the page, and if I remember well restful urls is the first topic in the talk.)

Comment: doesn't really help me since the slide says: "Demo - Supporting REST-like URLs" and there are no examples of it in the sample code :)

Comment: I have seen this video: http://events.boostweb20.com/Events/SeattleCodeCamp2010/#state=sessionCode%242003-4. If you have time look at it. :) It does show the demo about the restful urls....

Comment: Now that's a pretty sweet solution! :D

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a default for `{format}` of `html`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is an option (using '/' instead of '.'):

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Rest1",
        "Users/Get/{format}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Users", action = "Get", format = "HTML" }
        );
```

And then

```
public class UsersController : Controller {
   public ActionResult Get(string format, int id) {
      switch (format) {
         case "json":
            break;
         case "xml":
            break;
         default:
            break;
      }
      return new ContentResult(); // Or other result as required.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Rest1",
    "Users/Get/{id}.{format}",
    new { controller = "Users", action = "Get", format = "HTML" }
    );
```

And then in controler method add some code for retreaving id and format

Comment: well then /Users/Get/1 wont work... I would need to write "/Users/Get/1." in order for the route to work...

Answer (score 0):

You could use [regular expressions in your route](http://www.iridescence.no/post/Defining-Routes-using-Regular-Expressions-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx), then define that "." as an optional character in your route.